# iOS App is stuck at launch screen while Console showing: Attempting to create a breadcrumb action for a scene handle which already has one?

Tags: ios, launch, breadcrumbs, springboard

1.After downloading my app from TestFlight and then click it, or run from Xcode directly, the app is stuck on launch screen and cannot continue.

2.When connected with macOS, from the Console we can see some possibly related error in SpringBoard process:

```
Attempting to create a breadcrumb action for a scene handle which already has one (sceneID:#myAppName#-default). Are you trying to active an app that's already active?
...
[Main] dispatch event:
<SBMainTransitionSwitcherModifierEvent: 0x2837d7dc0; type: MainTransition; transitionID: xxx; phase: Complete; animated: YES; fromAppLayout: 0x0; toAppLayout: <SBAppLayout: 0x281500e80; primary: #myAppName#; environment: main>; fromEnvironmentMode: home-screen; toEnvironmentMode: application; pendingTermination: {(
)}>
```

The "pendingTermination: {()}" in this log does not appear when app can be launched normally.
And now we cannot see any logs in my app’s process.

3.Then when I lock the screen and unlock it, the iPhone shows nothing but a black background, and I cannot use my iPhone as usual. Here is the logs in the Console:

3.1 Lock screen:

```
[sceneID:#myAppName#-default] Setting deactivation reasons to: 'appSwitcher, systemAnimation' for reason: updateAllScenesForBand - Assertion added.
[sceneID:#myAppName#-default] Setting deactivation reasons to: 'appSwitcher' for reason: updateAllScenesForBand - Assertion removed.
Invalidating assertion 32-60-106090 (target:[application<#myAppName#>:7754](UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::sceneID%3A#myAppName#-default)) from originator [daemon<com.apple.SpringBoard>:60]
Calculated state for application<#myAppName#>: none (role: UserInteractiveNonFocal)
```

3.2 Unlock screen:

```
Acquiring assertion targeting [application<#myAppName#>:7754](UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::sceneID%3A#myAppName#-default) from originator [daemon<com.apple.SpringBoard>:60] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "injecting inherited from "UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::com.apple.springboard" to 7754<UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::sceneID%3A#myAppName#-default>" ID:32-60-106093 target:7754<UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::sceneID%3A#myAppName#-default> attributes:[
    <RBSHereditaryGrant| endowmentNamespace:com.apple.boardservices.endpoint-injection UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::com.apple.springboard>,
    <RBSHereditaryGrant| endowmentNamespace:com.apple.frontboard.visibility UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::com.apple.springboard>
    ]>
Assertion 32-60-106093 (target:[application<#myAppName#>:7754](UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::sceneID%3A#myAppName#-default)) will be created as active
Calculated state for application<#myAppName#>: none (role: UserInteractiveNonFocal)
Finished acquiring assertion 32-60-106093 (target:[application<#myAppName#>:7754](UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::sceneID%3A#myAppName#-default))
[sceneID:#myAppName#-default] Setting deactivation reasons to: 'appSwitcher, systemAnimation' for reason: updateAllScenesForBand - Assertion added.
[sceneID:#myAppName#-default] Setting deactivation reasons to: 'appSwitcher' for reason: updateAllScenesForBand - Assertion removed.
```

4.After rebooting my iPhone, everything return to normal again.

This bug has happened for several times recently, but I have not encounter this kind of issue before.

Is it a bug in SpringBoard? Or it is a bug in my app, and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find the reason of this issue?